# How to prevent a method from calling another method in test?

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, robolectric

```
public void makeLoginRequest(){
    view.log(sessionHandler.getEncodedCredentials());
    Call loginCall = apiService.getLoginInfo("application/json", "application/json"
            , "SPT", "Android", sessionHandler.getEncodedCredentials());

   loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            handleLoginResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            handleLoginFailure(t);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to test this method with JUnit and Mockito. This method belongs in a presenter class. In order to test this I run
`presenter.makeLoginRequest();` then when the onResponse is called
I use `verify(presenter).handleLoginResponse(response);` which never gets called. The issue is that it will continue to run everything in `handleLoginResponse(response);`. I don't want to execute whats in this method, but only need to verify that this method gets called.
How can I ignore the method execution, or what is the best way to test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There 2 ways of doing this:

1. Make your presenter become a `mock` object

```
presenter = mock<Presenter>()
```

2. Add this to your test

```
doNothing().when(presenter).handleLoginResponse(any());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mocked the presenter class but that causes the `handleLoginResponse(response)` to not be invoked. It would work when I spy the presenter class, although the `doNothing` is ignored and the method is still executed :(

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose is that the test does not invoke `handleLoginResponse`? Even if you mock the presenter class, `verify(presenter).handleLoginResponse(response);` can still verify

Comment: Actually it works! I just forgot to add the `any()` also inside the verify.
Thank you Bach! :)

Comment: Glad it helps  :)